How to create the exact UI component with the animation?
I tried creating the card component and gradient for the background along with the animation. But it was nowhere near the gif provided. How can I create smooth animation and exact gradient, and also make the card pop as shown in the image?
[NOTE: Please click the gif, it might not have rendered properly in the question section"]

import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import Card from "../Card";
import demoCardData from "../../constants/cardData";

export const ScrollableCardList = ({
  cardData: propCardData,
}: {
  cardData?: Array<any>;
}) => {
  const data = propCardData || demoCardData;
  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);

  const handleScroll = useCallback(() => {
    if (!containerRef.current) return;

    const scrollTop = containerRef.current.scrollTop;
    const scrollHeight = containerRef.current.scrollHeight;
    const clientHeight = containerRef.current.clientHeight;

    const scrollRatio = scrollTop / (scrollHeight - clientHeight);
    const newActiveIndex = Math.floor(scrollRatio * data.length);

    setActiveIndex(newActiveIndex);
  }, [data]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!containerRef.current) return;

    containerRef.current.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => {
      if (!containerRef.current) return;
      containerRef.current.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, [handleScroll]);

  return (
    <div
      ref={containerRef}
      className="flex flex-col items-center h-screen overflow-auto"
      style={{ scrollBehavior: "smooth" }}
    >
      {data.map((card, index) => (
        <Card
          key={uuidv4()}
          imageUrl={card.imageUrl}
          avatarImageUrl={card.avatarImageUrl}
          titleText={card.titleText}
          subTitleText={card.subTitleText}
          isActive={index === activeIndex}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

    
    import { Circular, Rectangular, SubTitle, Title } from "./placeholders";
    
    type CardProps = {
      isActive?: boolean;
      cardContainerStyles?: string;
      rectangleContainerStyles?: string;
      circleContainerStyles?: string;
      imageUrl?: string;
      avatarImageUrl?: string;
      titleText?: string;
      subTitleText?: string;
    };
    const Card = ({
      isActive,
      cardContainerStyles,
      rectangleContainerStyles,
      circleContainerStyles,
      imageUrl,
      avatarImageUrl,
      titleText,
      subTitleText,
    }: CardProps) => {
      const activeClass = isActive ? "scale-110" : "";
      // Ensure transition-transform is part of the base class string
      const cardBaseStyles = "transition-transform duration-300 ease-in-out";
      const cardDynamicStyles =
        cardContainerStyles ||
        "w-80 min-h-80 rounded-2xl shadow-4xl p-4 my-4 bg-gradient-to-br from-rose-500 to-rose-400";
      const cardStyles = `${cardBaseStyles} ${activeClass} ${cardDynamicStyles}`;
      const rectangleStyles =
        rectangleContainerStyles ||
        "bg-gradient-to-br from-rose-400 to-[#db7483] w-[100%] h-36 rounded-2xl shadow-2xl";
      const circleStyles =
        circleContainerStyles ||
        "w-12 h-12 rounded-full bg-gradient-to-br from-rose-400 to-rose-300 shadow-md";
    
      return (
        <div className={cardStyles}>
          <Rectangular rectangleStyles={rectangleStyles} imageUrl={imageUrl} />
          <div className="flex items-center mt-5">
            <Circular circleStyles={circleStyles} avatarImageUrl={avatarImageUrl} />
            <div className="flex-grow ml-4">
              <Title titleText={titleText} />
              <SubTitle subTitleText={subTitleText} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Card;


Should I've used the animation library? How could I create the exact gradient, popup effect, animation, etc? Can someone guide me through the process? If someone provides the solution great, if someone guides me through the way even better.
Thank you.
Here is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Habi-Thapa/rockandscroll/main?import=true

Please provide a live working example so that we can better help you. You could use codesandbox.

Hi, here is my codesandbox

This doesn't seem like a stackoverflow question.

To achieve the effect you described, you can modify your Card component styles dynamically based on the isActive prop that indicates whether it's the card currently in focus. You would also add a smooth scrolling and opacity effect to the card as it transitions into and out of focus.
Here's an implementation outline of what changes you might make to both the ScrollableCardList component and the Card component. Please keep in mind that while this example serves as a starting point, you may want to refine the types for improved code clarity and readability.
For the ScrollableCardList component:
Update the handleScroll function to determine the card that's closest to the center of the container rather than using the scroll ratio.
Add an additional state to handle the card size and opacity values.
Updated ScrollableCardList code:
// ... import and setup continues

export const ScrollableCardList = ({
  cardData: propCardData,
}: {
  cardData?: Array<any>;
}) => {
  const data = propCardData || demoCardData;
  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  const [cardStyles, setCardStyles] = useState<Array<any>>([]);

  const updateCardStyles = useCallback(() => {
    if (!containerRef.current) return;

    const cardElements = containerRef.current.children;
    const cardElementsArray = Array.from(cardElements);
    const containerCenter = containerRef.current.clientHeight / 2;

    const newCardStyles = cardElementsArray.map((cardEl, index) => {
      const cardRect = cardEl.getBoundingClientRect();
      const cardCenter = cardRect.top + cardRect.height / 2;
      const distanceFromCenter = Math.abs(containerCenter - cardCenter);
      const scale = 1 - Math.min(distanceFromCenter / containerCenter, 0.5); // Scale down max to 0.5
      return {
        scale: 0.5 + scale * 0.5, // Scale range: [0.5, 1]
        opacity: 0.5 + scale * 0.5, // Opacity range: [0.5, 1]
      };
    });
    
    setCardStyles(newCardStyles);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!containerRef.current) return;

    updateCardStyles();
    containerRef.current.addEventListener("scroll", updateCardStyles);

    return () => {
      if (!containerRef.current) return;
      containerRef.current.removeEventListener('scroll', updateCardStyles);
    };
  }, [updateCardStyles]);

  return (
    <div
      ref={containerRef}
      className="flex flex-col items-center h-screen overflow-auto"
      style={{ scrollBehavior: "smooth" }}
    >
      {data.map((card, index) => (
        <Card
          key={uuidv4()}
          imageUrl={card.imageUrl}
          avatarImageUrl={card.avatarImageUrl}
          titleText={card.titleText}
          subTitleText={card.subTitleText}
          style={{
            transform: `scale(${cardStyles[index]?.scale || 1})`,
            opacity: cardStyles[index]?.opacity || 1,
          }}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

For the Card component:
Modify the components to accept style as a prop and apply these styles to the main card element.
Here's how you might update the Card component to accept the new styles:
    // ... import and setup continues
    const Card = ({ imageUrl, avatarImageUrl, titleText, subTitleText,style }) => {
        return (
          <div className="card-container" style={{ ...style, 
               transition: 'transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s' }}>
            {/* Card content goes here */}
          </div>
         );
        };
    export default Card;

To give you a better visual understanding, I've created a fork of your CodeSandbox with the implemented changes. You can view and interact with the modified example here: CodeSandbox Demo
Make sure to appropriately modify the existing code according to the data structure and styles you want, adjust the transition speeds and other values to best fit the desired animation smoothness and visual effect.
I hope this helps you progress with your project.
Updated Link here => 

Hi can you please make the codeSandbox accessible? Can't access it. Getting the error
"Unable to access this workspace
It is likely that you are not a member..."

Hi ! Here is the public URL for the CodeSandbox project. Normally, anyone with this link should be able to access it. Give it another try, If you're still experiencing issues, you might want to clear your cache or try accessing the link using a different browser. Let me know if that works for you!

I wasn't able to add the link in the comment, but I have updated my response with the new link. You can find it towards the end of the original post.
